# Setting a column value for only one user depending on results

Tags: sql

I'm currently playing around with SQL and trying to find the best way to accomplish this:

I currently have a user table that has a user_id, organisation_id, registered_datetime. There are
a number of users in this table with different organisations. There may be 3 different users in
1 organisation, or 1 in 1 organisation, etc.

I have added a new column called admin_user and I am trying to string up an SQL statement together
to update the admin user column. There can only be one admin user per organisation, and I want
the user who registered the earliest for that organisation to be the admin.

I could do this manually but it would take time if I had a lot of users. What would be the best
way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

[image]

So I have a number of users like this with the columns. The ones highlighted are the users that has registered the earliest. I want to be able to set those users as an admin user. The only admin user within their organisation and set the rest to 0. 1 (Admin) 0 (Not Admin)

Comment: Please provide (1) sample data; (2) a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL query will mark `users` which `registered_datetime` are lowest in its `organisation_id` as admin.

```
UPDATE users SET admin_user = 1
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT u.user_id FROM users u
    WHERE u.registered_datetime IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM users iu
      WHERE iu.organisation_id = u.organisation_id AND iu.registered_datetime < u.registered_datetime
    )
)
```

You might want to update all users to `admin_user = 0` before this code, so all your users will have their values set.

One caveat here, if two users in one organisation were registered in exact same time, then both of them will be marked as administrators.

**Update**

I have added `u.registered_datetime IS NOT NULL` into the WHERE clause to filter out users with `NULL` in `registered_datetime`.

**MSSQL**

In MsSql server I usually solve this problem a in another way, by using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
WITH base AS (
    SELECT user_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY organisation_id ORDER BY registered_datetime ASC ) AS rn
    FROM user
    WHERE registered_datetime IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE user SET is_admin = 1
WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT base.user_id FROM base WHERE rn = 1
)
```

Comment: I realised that I seem to have a `NULL` value on one of the record for the `registered_datetime` and when I ran the query it also set that user to an admin even though there's already an admin within the organisation. It's just the fact it's not taking into account the null. I added `AND iu.registered_datetime is not NULL and u.registered_datetime is not NULL` but it is still updating that record. Can the statement be altered to take into account the possible NULL value within that column?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You are describing three different tables:

- `Users`
- `Organizations`
- `UserOrganizations`

The last has one row per user and per organization.  This provides the mapping between the two.  This can be called a "mapping" table, "junction" table, or "association" table.

How you implement one admin per organization depends on the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `admin_user` column. You need a column `isadmin`.
When a user is registered, if he is the first in the organization, then the `isadmin` column has the value 1, otherwise 0

Also, you can use the AAA query to find the administrator

```
SELECT `table`.`user_id`, MIN(`table`.`registered_datetime`) WHERE `organisation_id`=...
```

Comment: I am trying to set an admin user for each organisation. So the value of 1 would mean the user is an admin 0 for not an admin. How would I go about updating the admin values for each user? I would need to find the earliest registered user from each organisation and then set that user as the admin user.